# Nice Limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{n+k}\right)$

Tags: limits

How do I evaluate this limit?
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{n+k}\right)$$

Comment: Hint: Obviously the sum does not depend on $x$. Therefore the limit is equal to the value of the sum (for any given $n$).

Comment: @user, might it be a typo?

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya Surely, it is. Most probably $x$ shall be replaced with $n$. But there are also other possibilities.

Comment: sorry for the mistake

Comment: What is so "nice"? The answer is obviously $0$, the proof is easy.

Comment: How and  zero isn't  a nice answer

Comment: There i an answer below :) Just to compare, as an exercise what would happen with this brother: $\sum_{k=1}^n sin^2(\frac{\pi n}{n+k})$ ?

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

$$0 \leq   \sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{n+k}\right)\leq \frac {\pi^2}{{(n+k)}^2}\leq \frac {\pi^2}{n^2}$$
$$\implies 0 \leq   \sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{n+k}\right)\leq \frac {\pi^2}{n^2}$$

Take summation on inequality use [squeeze theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

Comment: If you still cannot proceed let me know.

Comment: As already suggested by @metamorphy the answer is indeed zero. Which I think you should figure out on your own :)