# Limit of a sum of squared sines

Tags: limits, analysis, solution-verification, riemann-sum

Following up on this question [Nice Limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{n+k}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3605091/nice-limit-lim-n-to-infty-sum-k-1n-sin2-left-frac-pink-right#comment7410608_3605091) .

Fix a real $a$ and consider the sum:

$$S(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n \sin^2\left(\frac{n^a\pi}{n+k}\right)$$

In the linked question it is shown that for $a=0$ the sum converges to zero for large $n$. It is also easy to show that for $a=1$ the sum diverges, recognizing a Riemann sum. The question comes naturally: what happens for different $a$ ?

My thoughts for the moment:

- For $0<a<1/2$ the sum converges to zero using the same arguments of the linked answer.
- For $1/2<a<1$ we can proceed like that. Using the Taylor series of $sin(x^2)$ we have that $sin(x^2) \ge x^2 - x^4/3$ so that:

$S(n) \ge \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n^{2a}\pi^2}{(n+k)^2} \left( 1-\left( \frac{n^a \pi}{n+k}\right)^2 \frac{\pi^2}{3}
 \right)$

now $0 \le \left( \frac{n^a \pi}{n+k}\right) \le \left( \frac{n^a \pi}{2n}\right) \rightarrow_{n} 0$ if $a<1$

so we can safely maximize the term in the parenthesis with a constant $K_1>0$ and remove one term:

$S(n) > K_1 \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n^{2a}\pi^2}{(n+k)^2} > K_2 \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n^{2a}}{n^2} = K_2 n^{2a-1}$

, where $K_2$ is an other positive constant. The last term diverges for $a>1/2$.

Is it correct till now ?

I think then that for $a=1/2$ the limit converges to a non-trivial value.
I also conjecture that it diverges for $a>1$.

For $a=1/2$ I have only naive arguments and for $a>1$ have no clue since the argument of the sine diverges and the sine oscillates for large arguments.

UPDATE: for $a>1$ I think one could try to define the angle $\alpha_k=\frac{n^a\pi}{n+k},k=1..n$. For large $n$ this rotates from $\frac{n^{a-1}\pi}{2}$ to $n^{a-1}\pi$. If one could prove that this angle remains "far" from $0$ and $\pi$ a sufficient number of times, divergence could than be proved.

Comment: Mathematica (11.3) claims your limit is zero for $a \in \{1/2, 3/4, 1\}$.  The $a = 1$ case is similar to the linked question, $\frac{\pi}{1+k/n}$ is clustered near $\pi$ and $\sin(\pi) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks. I am a bit puzzled because I experimented numerically with Python and I get different results. Maybe I made some mistake ? For $a=1$ we have $\sum_{k=1}^n \sin^2(\pi/(1+k/n))*1/n *n$ which should diverge like $\int_0^1 sin^2(\frac{\pi}{1+x})dx*n$ ?

Comment: Yeah, having thought for a bit, I don't believe the Mathematica results either.  This is not a sum of zeroes, so should not be zero.

Comment: Actually for some values of a it is a sum of nonzero terms but it can have a zero the limit (reaching it from above zero).

Answer (score 2):

For convenience, notations in the following proof are defined here.

> 1.$f(n)=\Theta(g(n))$ : there exist constans $A,B$ which are independent of $n$, such that
>   $$\exists N,\forall n\geqslant N, Ag(n)\leqslant f(n)\leqslant Bg(n).$$
>   2.$\psi'(x)$ : the second derivative of $\ln \Gamma(x)$.

There are some properties of $\psi'(x)$ in the link: http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.15.E8

For fixed $a\in (0,1)$, we have
$$\sin^2\frac{n^a\pi}{n+k}=\frac{n^{2a}\pi^2}{\left(n+k\right)^2}+\Theta\left(n^{4a-4}\right).$$
Thus as $n\to \infty$,
\begin{align*}
S(n)& =\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{n^{2a}\pi^2}{\left(n+k\right)^2}+\Theta\left(n^{4a-4}\right)\right)\\
& =n^{2a}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{\pi^2}{k^2}+\Theta\left(n^{4a-3}\right)\\
& =n^{2a}\pi^2\left\{\psi'(n+1)-\psi'(2n+1)\right\}+\Theta\left(n^{4a-3}\right)\\
& =n^{2a}\pi^2\left(\frac{1}{2n}+\Theta\left(n^{-2}\right)\right)+\Theta\left(n^{4a-3}\right)\\
& =\frac{\pi^2}{2}n^{2a-1}+\Theta\left(n^{\max\{2a-2,4a-3\}}\right).
\end{align*}
Thence
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}S(n)=
\begin{cases}
0& \mathrm{if}\ a<\frac{1}{2},\\
\frac{\pi^2}{2}& \mathrm{if}\ a=\frac{1}{2},\\
+\infty& \mathrm{if}\ a>\frac{1}{2}.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Nice answer and well done for getting the exact value at $a=1/2$. But I would just suggest to specify, if you think it is the case: (1) That the first expansion is valid because $\frac{n^{2a}\pi}{n+k} \rightarrow 0$ for large n at fixed $k$, under the assumption $0<a<1$. (2) Cite a reference, or at least the result, of the asymptotic expansion of $\psi$ that you use. (3) specify when you summarize the results that these do not include $a>1$ (4) Define $\Theta$ ( is it the standard big O notation or something else?) and $\psi$.

Comment: @Thomas Ok, I'll make the notations clear in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Thomas We can obtain the leading term of $S(n)$ without using $\psi'(x)$. Because there are some simple inequalities about $\sum_{k=n+1}^n\frac{1}{k^2}.However, it's direct and rapid to use $\psi'(x)$.

Comment: Great I put a +1 now. Even if I cannot accept the answer completely because it does not address the whole a range.

Comment: (at least if I am understanding well)